# input Dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Im new to python
i have problems with understanding Dictionaries in python
especially how to get them as input from user
Can smn explain it to me as an example on 1 task

[image: input line]

1 line is number of records
then Actor name and movies they played seperated by comma

[image: result]

output must be movie name:actor name,actor name

I dont undrestand what is key and what is value
How should i convert this input lines as dictionary ?

Comment: Use `line.split(', ')` to convert the line to a list. Loop through all the movies, making them keys in the dictionary with the actor name as the values.

Comment: You cannot input a newline into a python input... Is the "input from user" in fact a file?

Comment: i tried it and got List of lists [['Brad Pitt', 'Sleepers', 'Troy', 'Meet Joe Black', 'Oceans Eleven', 'Seven', 'Mr & Mrs Smith'], ['Tom Hanks', etc       the thing i rly dont understand is what then how to make dict from all this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
d = {}  # initialize empty dictionary
n = int(input()). # get number of input lines
for _ in range(n):
    actor, *films = input().split(", ")  # get actor and films
    for film in films:  # add actor to each film in dictionary
        d[film] = d.get(film, []) + [actor]

for film, actors in d.items():  # iterate the dictionary
    print(f"{film}: {', '.join(actors)}")  # print the data using join function to add "," character between films
```

If you need to sort keys and values of them add this code:

```py
for key, value in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    d[key] = sorted(value)
```

Comment: Thank u a lot for your time and answer rly i appreciate it Thanks

Comment: One more detail if u can  I sorted them by Keys and make Apollo first but  is there a way when i can sort Values in keys too        I mean      
 Sleepless in Seattle: Tom Hanks, Meg Ryan      to                                                     
 Sleepless in Seattle: Meg Ryan, Tom Hanks after sorting them by Keys

Comment: I edited my answer and added code to sort keys of the dictionary and values of them.

Comment: Thanks one more time

Answer (score 0):

initially, you just create an empty dictionary in python. Then input a number to loop a number of times you want to take input. Then put a for loop and input key and value and store them in the dictionary as dict[key]=value.

Here is the code sample in python

```
dict={} 
n=int(input())
for i in range(n):
    key=input()
    value=intput()
    dict[key]=value
```